# Non-commutative algebra

Tags: symbolic

I'm constantly dealing with non-commutative algebras. `**` is inbuilt, non-commutative and associative. That's good :-) But it is not distributive. Rats.

- What is a simple way (I probably won't need much more) to have, say, `(a1 + a2 + a3)**(b1 + b2 + b3)` always expand to `a1**b1 + ... + a3**b3`, on the fly?
- And if I like to add (also executed on the fly) laws like `a1**b1 = c1 + d1`?
- And, last question, if I did and have `a2**a1**b1` (with, say, `a2**a1 = e1`
  forced), do `(a2**a1)**b1` and `a2**(a1**b1)` substitute to `e1**b1` and
  `a2**(c1+d1)`, respectively, or both to `e1**b1` due to flatness of `**`?

Comment: Are you familiar with `UpValues`? The easiest thing to do would be to create your own symbol (to which you can set your own rules and infix). However, if it is important to still use `NonCommutativeMultiply` you can in theory unprotect it, then add `UpValues`, but that is frowned upon and a bit dangerous.

Comment: There is of course `Distribute[(a1 + a2 + a3) ** (b1 + b2 + b3)]` as well.

Comment: For distribution you should consult the second application of NCM in [Mathematica Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html#).

Answer (score 32):

I recommend you try the [NCAlgebra package](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/) if you are going to do these kinds of computations.  It is a mature package that has been under development for many years.  The function you are looking for is `NCExpand`.

Comment: I will never grow tired of upvoting an answer suggesting this package. +1

Comment: THX! Frankly, the _existence_ of such a package doesn't surprise me in the least, but still being a MATHEMATICA n00b, I would have googled _minutes_ for it :-) I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something lighter-weight than NCAlgebra you can do things like

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[H___, Plus[a_, addends_], T___] :=  NonCommutativeMultiply[H, a, T] + 
    NonCommutativeMultiply[H, Plus[addends], T]

NonCommutativeMultiply[H___, a1, b1, T___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[H, c1 + d1, T]
```

Then `(a1 + a2 + a3)**(b1 + b2 + b3)` evaluates to

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[c1] + NonCommutativeMultiply[d1] + a1 ** b2 + 
a1 ** b3 + a2 ** b1 + a2 ** b2 + a2 ** b3 + a3 ** b1 + a3 ** b2 + a3 ** b3
```

where the only "issue" is that the singletons are wrapped with a `NonCommutativeMultiply`.

If you add

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[H___, a2, a1, T___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[H, e1, T]
```

then, at least with `$Version="12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"`, your first paren example gives `e1**b1` and the other gives `a2 ** c1 + a2 ** d1`.