# Distributive Concatenation

Tags: function-construction

I'd like to have an (obviously noncommutative) operator `**` that always takes linear combinations of some (undefined) `F` with any number arguments, distributes the coefficients out and concatenates the arguments. Example:

```
(2*F[]+3*F[a,b]) ** (5*F[c])

10*F[c]+15*F[a,b,c]
```

Surely this can be done very elegantly? (Unfortunately, a property "Distributive" is not settable as attribute. When I do linear algebra, I miss such a feature each day...)

Comment: You might want to take a look at the answer to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261282/noncommutative-multiplication-with-rational-functions-as-coefficients/263386#263386question), which is very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how automatic or "pretty" you want this, but just implementing the description you gave could be done something like this:

```
myProd[a_ A_F, b_ B_F] := a b Join[A, B];
myProd[x_, y_] := ReleaseHold[Distribute[Hold[myProd][x, y]]];
```

Then, to reproduce your example:

```
(2*F[] + 3*F[a, b])~myProd~(5*F[c])
```

which outputs

```
10 F[c] + 15 F[a, b, c]
```

Now, I personally think it'd be better to build out some custom structures, basically define your own little algebra.

Comment: I definitely agree with the last statement, but if this special need is only use-once, a "cheap" solution suffices. P.S. Never saw some details of the syntax (A_F? Tilde is betweenfix notation?) but I learn fast :)